# Using the values returned by a 'select' in ActiveRecord Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have two models

```
class Shoot < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :questionnaires
end

class Questionnaire < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :shoot
end
```

The Shoot and the Questionnaire models have both an attribute called **positive_feedback**.

I'm trying to update the positive_feedback attribute in the shoot using the value taken from the positive_feedback of the Questionnaire. **Only one** questionnaire in shoots have a positive_feedback with value. The rest will contain nil or an empty string value. So I'm not worried in my query about having more than one questionnaire per shoot with a value in the positive_feedback attribute

I'm trying to get a better approach than my current one.

I'm doing something like this, but I'm not happy with that:

```
selected_values = Shoot.joins(:questionnaires).where.not(questionnaires: {positive_feedback: ['', nil]}).select('questionnaires.positive_feedback AS feedback', 'shoots.id')


selected_values.each do |selected_values|
     Shoot.find(selected_values.id).update_attribute(:positive_feedback, selected_values.feedback)
end
```

I'm pretty sure that there is a better way of avoiding the loop for each value that I want to update, but I can't find it.

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

### **Edit**

Part of the **schema.rb** related to this:

```
...
create_table "shoots", force: true do |t|
    ...
    t.text     "positive_feedback"
    t.string   "status"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    ...
end

...

create_table "questionnaires", force: true do |t|
    ...
    t.integer  "shoot_id"
    t.boolean  "enabled",          default: true
    t.text     "positive_feedback"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    ...
end
add_index "questionnaires", ["shoot_id"], name: "index_questionnaires_on_shoot_id", using: :btree
```

Hope it helps Prometheus

### **Edit II**

Thank you max and sorry, the relationship between these models is a little bit more extensive than I'm showing. Trying to reduce the complexity of the case I wrote some errors in my first edit. TBH it's a has many through association, but I'm trying to reduce the complexity of the comprehension. I've corrected the assumptions.
Anyway, what I'm trying to get is just a way to optimize the ActiveRecord query that I posted at the begging.

Comment: Hey! Could you post your schema.rb file?

Comment: Why do you pass all values within params if you're using only one?

Comment: Hi Prometheus, Sorry but the schema has a lot of things that don't make sense having here. Do you need something specific from the schema? Basically, Questionnaire has a one-to-many connection with Shoot. One Shoot can have multiple questionnaires and one questionnaire is related only with one shoot.

Comment: Sorry @escanxr but I'm not following you. What do you mean with passing all values within params?

Comment: Your assocations are completely wrong. You need to create a `shoot_id` column on the `questionaires` table (you can generate it with `rails g migration add_shoot_to_questionaires shoot:references`) and you need to use `belongs_to :shoot` instead of `has_one`. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one

Comment: The way you have set it up a shoot can only have one questionaire because you have the foreign key on the wrong table and the has_many assocation won't work since it expects the foreign key (questionarie_id) to be on the other table (shoots).